# Does k-PATH admit a constant approximation?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, approximation-algorithms

In the $k$-PATH problem, we receive as input a graph $G$ and an integer $k$. The goal is to decide whether there exists a simple path of length $k$ in $G$.

A $\alpha$-approximation for $k$-PATH is an algorithm which given an input $\langle G,k\rangle$ either confirms that a path of length $k/\alpha$ exists in $G$, or denies the existence of a $k$-path. It may act arbitrarily if the longest simple path in $G$ is at least of size $k/\alpha$ and at most of size $k$.

**Is there a constant $\alpha>0$ for which $k$-PATH is $\alpha$-approximable in poly time?**

Comment: Gabow's paper on finding long paths of super poly-logarithmic length  is interesting and relevant. http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0097539704445366

Comment: There is also a paper on hardness for the longest path problem in directed graphs. http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-27836-8_21#page-1

Answer (score 6):

Karger, Motwani and Ramkumar (1997) discuss this question.
They show that if any polynomial-time algorithm can approximate the longest path to a ratio of $2^{O(\log^{1−\epsilon} n)}$, for any $\epsilon>0$, then NP has a quasi-polynomial deterministic time simulation; this results even holds for graphs of bounded degree.

> David R. Karger, Rajeev Motwani, G. D. S. Ramkumar:
>   On Approximating the Longest Path in a Graph.
>   Algorithmica 18(1): 82-98 (1997)

Comment: My impression (from the one seeming clarification I found during my skim of that paper) was that their results are about _finding_ a fairly long path, rather than just approximating the length of the longest paths. ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer The hardness reduction should work for the length as well.